# Filter Windows Eventlog with XPath-Filter

Tags: xpath, event-log

I try to filter a windows event log for "real" interactive logon/unlock-events. For this I have written the following XPath-filter condition:

```
*[System
    [EventID=4624]
    [TimeCreated[@SystemTime>'2022-02-09T15:38:26']]
]
[EventData
    [Data
        [@Name='LogonType'] and 
        (Data=2 or Data=7 or Data=10 or Data=11)
    ] 
    [Data
        [@Name='WorkstationName'] and
        (Data!='-')
    ]
]
```

but for any reason the last condition is not filtering anything. I still see event with WorkstationName = '-'. Even if I negate the condition it gives me the exact same events back. How do I need to configure the filter to have 2 conditions based on EventData combined with and AND-logic?

In case you want to test it in the EventLog-Viewer here the full Filter-XML (skipping the time-filter):

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
    <Select Path="Security">
 Event
    [System
        [EventID=4624]
    ]
    [EventData
        [Data
            [@Name='LogonType'] and 
            (Data=2 or Data=7 or Data=10 or Data=11)
       ]
       [Data
            [@Name='WorkstationName'] and
            (Data!='-')
        ]
    ] 

</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

Comment: After some more testing it looks like the issue is not the AND-logic but filtering for the "-" character. If I replace "-" with any other string it is doing exactly what it should do. Does it needs a special way to check for "-"?

Comment: After some more tests it looks to me, like MS has not implemented the "not equal" logic for strings (!=) for filtering the EventLog. Is there a workaround to negate a bool expression?

Answer (score 0):

Use:
<Select Path="Security">*[System[EventID=4624] and [TimeCreated[@SystemTime>'2022-02-09T15:38:26']] and [EventData[Data            [@Name='LogonType'] and (Data=2 or Data=7 or Data=10 or Data=11)]</Select>
<Suppress>*[EventData[Data[@Name='WorkstationName']='-']]</Suppress>

You select events you are interested in (in the example above specific authentication events), then suppress those you are not interested in. No limit on the number of suppress lines. Only issue is exact match is expected, you cannot use regular expressions or wildcards.

Comment: Does it mean I HAVE to use XML instead of XPath? I still looking for the correct XPath condition.